# Can I disable "cut scenes"?

Tags: runner2

Everytime I load the game, I first have to go through Charles Martinee advertising some ingame brand, then an explanation that advises me to use an Xbox controller.  Afterwars, when starting the game, I have to watch him explain how Commander Video gets lost.  When starting the first level of any world, I'll have to watch him explain how Commander Video gets there.

Can I skip these without actually watching? I know pressing "Spacebar" skips them, but I'd rather not see them at all.  Are there any options that disable them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, not at all, unfortunately.